# Not sure where to put this code for my custom post type?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom post type (called 'discount') that I am trying to display in the twentythirteen theme. I created a custom page file called discount-page.php to create my own template for this post type. I'm not sure where I need to place the wp_query code, however. Here's what the default page.php looks like, with an addition of the new template name:

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

        <?php /* The loop */ ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>


            <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                <header class="entry-header">
                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() && ! post_password_required() ) : ?>
                    <div class="entry-thumbnail">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                </header><!-- .entry-header -->

                <div class="entry-content">
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                    <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-links"><span class="page-links-title">' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentythirteen' ) . '</span>', 'after' => '</div>', 'link_before' => '<span>', 'link_after' => '</span>' ) ); ?>
                </div><!-- .entry-content -->

                <footer class="entry-meta">
                    <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentythirteen' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
                </footer><!-- .entry-meta -->
            </article><!-- #post -->

            <?php comments_template(); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
```

Now, I'm fairly sure that in order for my posts to actually show their content, I need to add this block of code to the discount-page.php:

```
<?php
 $query = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'discount', 'posts_per_page' => 5 ) );
 while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
// Your code e.g. "the_content();"
<?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

I just have no idea where to add it? It seems to break the page no matter where I add it.

Comment: You'll need to put it outside of the main loop, either somewhere before or after.  So before this: `<?php /* The loop */ ?>` or after this: `<?php endwhile; ?>`.

Comment: Also, place your `endif;` from this line `<?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>` with `endwhile;` and remove the last line in your custom loop, which is this: `<?php endwhile; ?>`.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. So this is what I ended up with as my code: http://pastebin.com/VNnukriV but It seems to have broken my page. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your pastebin code is not correct, give me a couple minutes to sort through it and I'll post again.

Comment: Are you looking to have the main loop in addition to the custom loop, or just the custom loop only?

Comment: Okay so I changed up the code to this http://pastebin.com/npCnTSVj and while it no longer breaks my page, it doesn't show any of the content? Not sure why

Comment: Try this: http://pastebin.com/NsQNr29H.  You are opening a loop, and then opening another loop, and there are not content tags for the first loop.  The pastebin above should show your CPT loop, then your main loop.  You shouldn't open a loop inside of another loop.

Comment: If it works, I'll post it as an answer so you can accept it.

Comment: I tried it but no content showed. Here's what I see: http://thriftyus.hlwebsites.com/grid-test/ (please ignore the horrible everything, this page is just for testing)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57275/discussion-between-andywarren-and-harry).

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change a couple of lines of code for it to work.

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

        <?php /* The loop */ ?>
        <?php 
            $query = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'discount', 'posts_per_page' => 5 ) );
            while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?> ?>


            <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                <header class="entry-header">
                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() && ! post_password_required() ) : ?>
                    <div class="entry-thumbnail">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                </header><!-- .entry-header -->

                <div class="entry-content">
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                    <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-links"><span class="page-links-title">' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentythirteen' ) . '</span>', 'after' => '</div>', 'link_before' => '<span>', 'link_after' => '</span>' ) ); ?>
                </div><!-- .entry-content -->

                <footer class="entry-meta">
                    <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentythirteen' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
                </footer><!-- .entry-meta -->
            </article><!-- #post -->

            <?php comments_template(); ?>
        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
```

If you want the super simple version of it removing everything else. Try this:

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
        <?php 
            $query = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'discount', 'posts_per_page' => 5 ) );
            while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); 
        ?>
            <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                <div class="entry-content">
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                </div>
            </article>
        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This will work if he does not need a main loop on the page to display the page content.  Just wanted to clarify that you're replacing his main loop with a custom post type loop.

Comment: Thanks! The first block of code shows my custom posts but it doesn't link to them. Any idea how to add this functionality?

Comment: It should be single-discount.php (I don't believe page-discount.php will work or the way you had it before).

Comment: Not unless he wants a custom template for the single posts of this post type. 

If you just want the post titles to link to the post, change `<h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>` to `<h1 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>`.

Comment: As its a post type, you will need to have that code in a file named archive-discount.php. You can override it with a function in the functions.php file but i may mess up further down the line